# Multiple stores in one domain magento 2

Tags: magento2, stores, multiple, domain

I have created two stores with different themes. I want the first one to be loaded on http://example.local and the second one on http://example.local/shop.

Code for my second store view and I check Add Store Code to Urls in `|Stores| -> |Configuration| -> |Web|`.

When I go to http://example.local/shop, only html is loaded and in console I get this error:

```
The resource from “http://example.local/version1500395539/frontend/.../css-fix.css” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More]  shop
The resource from “http://example.local/shop/shop/pub/.../css/config_3.css” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More]  shop
The resource from “http://example.local/version1500395539/frontend/.../css/swatches.css” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More]  shop
The resource from “http://example.local/version1500395539/frontend/.../css/styles-m.css” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More]  shop
```

I try to deploy, permissions are fine, so, does any one have any idea what could it be?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you try to use symlinks?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use symlinks? Example:

If you have 2 shops and you want to show them under one domain than you can create a symlink structure.

Go with your console, like putty in your root folder.

Than create the symlink like

```
   ln -s /user/5222_02222/website/yourshopmain/app/ app
   ln -s /user/5222_02222/website/yourshopmain/lib/ lib
   ln -s /user/5222_02222/website/yourshopmain/pub/ pub
   ln -s /user/5222_02222/website/yourshopmain/var/ var
```

After that you create a new folder like my example:

New folder in root

```
+
+-website
|
|-+--yourshopmain
|-+--subdomain
```

The "subdomain" is your other shop name.